# How to match and select values from dataframes in different length?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames of different length. Each has 3 id columns, I would like to transfer the value from the second data frame to the first one only when all the id columns are the same. For example, the value 'bb' will be added to a new column in df1 at the 3rd row. How should I do it?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1' : [1, 2, 'aa', 4, 5], 'id2': ['a', 'a', 'aa', 'd','e'], 'id3': ['p', 'r', 'aa', 'i', 't']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id1': [ 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 'aa' ], 'id2':['f','d','c','f','b','z','aa'], 'id3':['a', 'f', 'q',  'b', 't', 't','aa'], \
                'value' : [5, 4,7,6, 8, 5 , 'bb']})
    id1 id2 id3
0   1   a   p
1   2   a   r
2  aa  aa  aa
3   4   d   i
4   5   e   t

[5 rows x 3 columns]
  id1 id2 id3 value
0   6   f   a     5
1   7   d   f     4 
2   6   c   q     7
3   5   f   b     6
4   4   b   t     8
5   1   z   t     5
6  aa  aa  aa    bb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just perform a left style [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [116]:
df1.merge(df2, how='left')

Out[116]:
  id1 id2 id3 value
0   1   a   p   NaN
1   2   a   r   NaN
2  aa  aa  aa    bb
3   4   d   i   NaN
4   5   e   t   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems really easy!